# Always open a link in a private or incognito window, not a tab but a window

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, private-browsing

I want to open links in a new window which is in incognito, beyond, next to another incognito which is already open (so not opening the link via a new tab, in the same incognito window).
in shell/open/command, what can I use instead of --incognito %1 ? I need the the "command line" for both, Chrome and Edge, for Edge, it's --inprivate %1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--new-window` parameter works for both.

So for Chrome:

```
start chrome --incognito --new-window www.superuser.com
```

And for Edge:

```
start msedge --inprivate --new-window www.superuser.com
```